# How to install libsrtp 1.5 on Centos 7?

Tags: yum

```
yum install libsrtp
```

Gives me v 1.4.4-10

How can I force install the >=1.5 version instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.4.4-10 of `libsrtp` is the latest version available from the CentOS repos. To get a later version, you'll need to compile it from source. You can get the source code here:

https://github.com/cisco/libsrtp/releases

All of the versions from 1.5.0 up to the current 2.2.0 are available.

After compiling, you will need to either prepend the libraries to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or create a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d with the path to the `libsrtp` libraries inside and then run `ldconfig` so that the system will add it to the library path.